# Matching string with multilayered array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

How can i match variable car with variable array? I need to match every first item (Buick, Mercedes, Chevrolet) with my string. I this case should be logged Buick and Chevrolet:

```
var car = "Buick, Chevrolet";
var array = [
  ["Buick", "2012", "USA", "1201"],
  ["Mercedes", "2005", "Germany", "12354"],
  ["Chevrolet", "1974", "USA", "9401"]
];


if (car = array) {
  console.log("Buick and Chevrolet matches.");  
};
```

But string could be different - sometimes may be matched items 0, sometimes 30 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In modern Javascript you use `Set` and `.filter` for this:

```js
var car = "Buick, Chevrolet";
var array = [
  ["Buick", "2012", "USA", "1201"],
  ["Mercedes", "2005", "Germany", "12354"],
  ["Chevrolet", "1974", "USA", "9401"]
];

var searchCars = new Set(car.match(/\w+/g));
var found = array.filter(([name]) => searchCars.has(name));

console.log(found);
```

Comment: Nice one, didn't know `Set` sound's cool, I will take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string and iterate for every element and check against the array.

```js
var car = "Buick, Chevrolet",
    array = [["Buick", "2012", "USA", "1201"], ["Mercedes", "2005", "Germany", "12354"], ["Chevrolet", "1974", "USA", "9401"]],
    match = car.split(', ').every(function (a) {
        return array.some(function (b) { return a === b[0]; });
    });

console.log(match);
```

```js
var car = "Buick, Chevrolet",
    array = [["Buick", "2012", "USA", "1201"], ["Mercedes", "2005", "Germany", "12354"], ["Chevrolet", "1974", "USA", "9401"]],
    match = car.split(', ').every(function (a) {
        return array.some(function (b) { return a === b[0]; });
    });
if (match) {
    console.log(car.split(', ').join(' and ') + ' matches.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` check for element with `indexOf()`

```js
var car = "Buick, Chevrolet";
var array = [
  ["Buick", "2012", "USA", "1201"],
  ["Mercedes", "2005", "Germany", "12354"],
  ["Chevrolet", "1974", "USA", "9401"]
];

var result = array.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  if (car.indexOf(e[0]) != -1) {
    r.push(e[0]);
  }
  return r;
}, []).join(' and ') + ' matches.';

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce` here

```js
var car = "Buick, Chevrolet";
var array = [
  ["Buick", "2012", "USA", "1201"],
  ["Mercedes", "2005", "Germany", "12354"],
  ["Chevrolet", "1974", "USA", "9401"]
];


var matches = array.reduce(function(result, item){
  if(car.indexOf(item[0]) > -1) result.push(item);
  
  return result
}, []);

console.log(matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop over array and you can check for match using `string.indexOf()`

```js
var car = "Buick, Chevrolet";
var array = [
  ["Buick", "2012", "USA", "1201"],
  ["Mercedes", "2005", "Germany", "12354"],
  ["Chevrolet", "1974", "USA", "9401"]
];
var matches = [];
var matchesStr = "";
array.forEach(function(item){
  if(car.indexOf(item[0]) > -1){
    matches.push(item[0]);
  }
});

if(matches.length > 0){
  var _last = matches.pop();
  matchesStr = matches.toString() + " and " + _last;
}
else{
  matchesStr = matches.toString()
}
console.log(matchesStr)
```

Also, if you have option to update your structure, its better to have array of object instead of array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Using array operations filter and map you can produce the desired filtering. First  filter the array to get only elements that match the search criteria. Then I map it to extract only data that is required for further operation.

```
var string = "Buick, Chevrolet";
var cars = [
  ["Buick", "2012", "USA", "1201"],
  ["Mercedes", "2005", "Germany", "12354"],
  ["Chevrolet", "1974", "USA", "9401"]
];

var findCars= function( arr, str ){
   return arr.filter(
         function(s){
              return str.indexOf(s[0])!==-1;
         }
    ).map(
       function(x){
         return x[0];
       }
    );
}

var res = findCars(cars, string);
console.log( res.join(" and ") + " matches.")
```

If you need the whole matching data item later, then you should skip the mapping of the result and findCars method will look like this:

```
var findCars= function( arr, str ){
   return arr.filter(
         function(s){
              return str.indexOf(s[0])!==-1;
         }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var car = "Buick, Chevrolet";
var array = [
  ["Buick", "2012", "USA", "1201"],
  ["Mercedes", "2005", "Germany", "12354"],
  ["Chevrolet", "1974", "USA", "9401"]
];

var result = car
              .split(', ')
              .reduce(
                (res, car) =>
                  (array.some(([arrayCar]) => car === arrayCar ? res.push(car) : null), res),
                []);

console.log(`${result.join(' and ')} matches`);
```